# Merging multiple feature classes into one using Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, merge, feature-class

So I have feature classes from an ArcGIS database that I renamed using this Python code: [image]

But now I have to merge all the feature classes that are output from this into one feature class named OSRS_ORN_NER. I'm not really sure how I should assign the inputs and outputs when I'm using the arcpy.Merge_management() tool. This is all I have right now: [image]

Comment: Please try to always include the text (not screenshots) of code and errors because that way they can be searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge tool expect you a list of feature classes as the input. so you shouldn't put it in a loop.

First build a list of feature classes in loop:

```
#l is a list of featureclasses with absolute path
l = [] 

for r in rows:
 # r is a featureclass like  "D:\FDB.gdb\input1"
 l.append(r)

arcpy.Merge_management(l, "D:\FGDB.gdb\Merged")
```

Comment: Would I name it OSRS_ORN_NER like this?: arcpy.Merge_management(l,"D:\FGDB.gdb\Merged\OSRS_ORN_NER")

Comment: You can name it any thing. Merged is just a sample  name of output featureclass in the file geodatabase. you can name it for example OSRS_ORN_NER.